# C++ makefile for CPLEX with environment loading

Tags: c++, makefile

CPLEX is a solver for mathematical problems made by IBM, and it offers callable C libraries.

My usual project configuration is a `main.cpp` file will all the important code and a simple `cpxmacro.h` file with some macros. Sometimes there are also .dat files with problem data. When the solver does its job (i.e. the `main` is run), it outputs .lp and .sol files.

I used to let my IDE come up with proper make files, but this time I was provided with a hand-made make file. What a good opportunity to look into it.

```make
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -O
LDADD =

CPX_INCDIR  = /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/include
CPX_LDPATH  = /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic
CPX_LDADD = -lcplex -lm -pthread

OBJ = main.o 

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(CPX_INCDIR) -c $^ -o $@

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o main -L$(CPX_LDPATH) $(CPX_LDADD)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) main

.PHONY: clean
```

As long as I only change the main file, it works. I just have to manually load a small file first, by typing `. cplex_env`. This is what the file contains:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/opl/bin/x86-64_linux:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/opl/bin/x86-64_linux:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cpoptimizer/bin/x86-64_linux/
```

I never tried to change the .h macro file and see what happens, it doesn't look to me like it's being accounted for anywhere in the makefile.

I'd like to:

- include the path exports in the make file
- make the makefile a little more generic

Comment: Minor suggestions: `CC` (C compiler) -> `CXX` (C++ compiler); `CPPFLAGS` (C preprocessor flags) -> `CXXFLAGS` (C++ compiler flags); `CPX_LIBDIR` -> `CPX_LDPATH`; `CPX_LDFLAGS` -> `CPX_LDADD`; `LDFLAGS` -> `LDADD`.

Comment: @Agostino: You should use `CXX=g++`. **BUT** also replace all locations where you use `CC` with `CXX`. If you are writing C++ code use the correct variables ore represent it.

Comment: @Gluttton renamings done and makefile working again. Is there anything else I can do? E.g. why is LDADD empty, and why should I call it like that instead of LDFLAGS?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing your own `%.o: %.cpp` rule, you can let Make use its built-in one.  You need to pass your extra include directory, and the standard way to do that is to add to `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I$(CPX_INCDIR)
```

Or perhaps

```
CPLEX_DIR = /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex
CXXFLAGS += -I$(CPLEX_DIR)/include
```

---

Similarly, take advantage of the built-in link command; this is especially easy, as there's a built-in rule that will create `main` from `main.o`.  You need to tell Make to use the C++ linker rather than the plain (C) linker:

```
LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
LDFLAGS += -L$(CPLEX_DIR)/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic
LDLIBS += -lcplex -lm -pthread
```

---

To declare the dependency on the header file, note that `main.o` needs to be rebuilt whenever the header changes:

```
main.o: cpxmacro.h
```

That's all!

Header file dependencies can be hard to manage by hand in larger projects; for these, search for "automatic dependency generation", or read Paul D. Smith's [excellent article](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

---

## Modified makfile

With my changes:

```
CPLEX_DIR = /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -O
CXXFLAGS += -I$(CPLEX_DIR)/include

LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
LDFLAGS += -L$(CPLEX_DIR)/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic
LDLIBS += -lcplex -lm -pthread


all: main

main.o: cpxmacro.h


clean:
    $(RM) *~ *.o main

.PHONY: all clean
```